# Add Failthrough server of a LAN IP to Nginx?

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to add my machine's LAN IP as a 'failthrough' location to use in the event the main server has issues.

Lately, my main server name (i.e. https://myserver.domain.com) has been having some issues due to LetsEncrypt certs issues, so any URL running on my server using that domain name fails as well. What I want is to have Nginx automatically pass it to the machine's IP instead if it detects the domain name itself is down.

I'm using the Docker [LinuxServer LetsEncrypt container](https://hub.docker.com/r/linuxserver/letsencrypt), and I've tried just adding the IP to the `server_name` variable in the config, but after restarting the container, nothing appears to change when trying to navigate to https://myserver.domain.com (it still just gives the same error page instead of redirecting to the IP).

Here's the current config with the issue:

```
server {

    listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;

    root /config/www;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name myserver.* 192.168.0.194:3333;

    # enable subfolder method reverse proxy confs
    include /config/nginx/proxy-confs/*.subfolder.conf;

    # Tell search engines not to crawl/add this domain
    add_header X-Robots-Tag "noindex, nofollow, nosnippet, noarchive";

    # all ssl related config moved to ssl.conf
    include /config/nginx/ssl.conf;

    # enable for ldap auth
    #include /config/nginx/ldap.conf;

    client_max_body_size 0;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Note this line in particular; the IP as the second server is the intended failthrough IP:

`server_name myserver.* 192.168.0.194:3333;`

Also note: if I just use `https://192.168.0.194:3333` directly in a browser, it navigates to the intended page fine, so this has to be something config-wise with Nginx that I'm trying to solve. It seems like a pretty simple issue, but I'm not super familiar with Nginx config nuances yet.